# how to make heading title into the center in asp:GridView

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know how can I center a title to the center in asp:GridView?

Example:

[image]

and my code as below:

```
<table border="0" width="500">
<tr>
    <td width="450px" align="center">
            <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              DataSourceID="dsTest" DataKeyNames="id"
              CellPadding="6" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True" Width="450px">
              <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="   Address" SortExpression="suburb, street">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                        <a style='cursor:pointer'  href='#'>
                     <%# Eval("unit_number") %> <%# Eval("level_number") %> <%# Eval("street_number") %> <%# Eval("street") %>
                     <%# Eval("suburb") %> <%# Eval("postcode") %></a>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone know how can I make the 'Address' to the center instead? I have tried to set a text-align:"center" in css for GridView, but it's doesn't seem working for me

Also... if I like to more all display address to the left, does anyone know how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's `HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="suburb, street" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
```

Comment: its actually the same <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /> or HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign within the tag

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 and creating a “Web Application” as I did. None of these options work. Mostly because the above commands are being over-ridden by a call-out in the Bootstrap.css file. 
How to fix this - After inserting the table on the web page you need to open Bootstrap.css under the Content folder in Solution explorer. 
I did a search for “Table” and found that at line 1419, there were two “Table” styles called out that surrounded a “th” style. "th" being the "Table Header". It was set by default to “text-align: left;”. Simply change "left" to “center” and all works fine. 
Below is a snippet from the default Bootstrap.css file that I found and altered.  On mine it started at line 1413 and ended on line 1426.

```
table {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align:center;
}
th {
  text-align: center;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you use bootstrap

,the Column 's title is Left align because of bootstrap.css 's th.

I guess some css may override your table head.

[bootstrap th style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tApSU.png)

So you need to override the bootstrap css that edit the head of table.
As Mohammad answer you can override all the table is the page.

or just use this style, that select the  of the specific table (select by table's class).

```
 <style>
                table.table_class tbody  tr th  
                {
                 text-align:center !important;
                }

 </style>

  <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Gv_Data" 
                CssClass="table_class " 
    ...
```

And for the content data to left for asp:TemplateField , you must find some tag that relate to ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign try to code below

```
     <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                      <ItemTemplate >
                       ...   

                      </ItemTemplate>

                  </asp:TemplateField>
```

and for asp:BoundField you can do it like this

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="rownum" HeaderText="ลำดับที่" ItemStyle-
    HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
```

p.s. < HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /> won't help you because it will be overridden by bootstrap , and too bad even the class text-center of bootstrap will be overridden  too.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a css class to center it

```
<style type="text/css">
    .header-center{
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```

Then just add HeaderStyle-CssClass:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="suburb, street" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

inside the `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="suburb, street">` tag

Comment: There might be a css that overrides the settings, check how did you get that red background its not on the code you give and no CssClass was indicated which makes me think there is a CSS that overrides it

Comment: <HeaderStyle CssClass="ui-widget-header" Width="500px"/> is the code I used to code the red bar

Comment: and what is the `ui-widget-header` maybe this class override the setting :(

Comment: if you can edit that css add the following property text-align:center then hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

If using `<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />` doesn't work, make sure your site is not added into the Compatibility View list in IE(I had the same issue and removing the web server from the list resolved the issue for me).

to remove the site, select the settings cog in IE and then select 'Compatibility View Settings' and if you're site is within the list, remove it.

Once removed, `<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />` (or any other variation) should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

simple just add the below mention style to your web form

```
<style>
th[scope=col]{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me
**HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center"**

Comment: To make this answer useful to other users it's best to post your solution with an example of how it could be implemented (a bit of code showing how you might use it). When I look at your answer in the editor, I see you have some portion which is not displaying correctly, would you be able to format it as code (if that is what it was), so you others can view it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Site.css file and add

```
.Center {
    text-align:center;
}
```

I would not modify the bootstrap.css file just in case you upgrade or reinstall...your changes could get overriden.

Now you can add a **HeaderStyle or ItemStyle** tag using **Center** for the **CssClass** property

```
<asp:BoundField ….>
   …...
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="Center" Width="10px" Wrap="False" />
  <ItemStyle CssClass="Center" Width="10px" Wrap="False" />
</asp:BoundField>
```