# Align Header Text Center asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am displaying some content in gridview , everything is working fine except the alignment of the grid.

I am trying to center-align the text of Header but nothing is working fine.

I tried this :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Gv_Edu" runat="server" BackColor="White" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
   BorderColor="#000000" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4"
  ForeColor="Black" OnRowDataBound="Gv_Edu_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr.No">
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="srlbl" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
<ItemTemplate>
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
  </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Degree / Certificate" DataField="deg">
   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="30%" />
  </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Institute" DataField="inst">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="20%" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Program Duration" DataField="term">
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
       </asp:BoundField>
      </Columns>
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code to the template fields in aspx?

```
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
```

Comment: I've used boundfield and everything is fine, just for styling , I can't change the logics

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852453/how-to-make-heading-title-into-the-center-in-aspgridview you can see it will not work

Comment: Can you try adding the same in BoudField? If that does not work, then you have to might have to create a css class to handle that. Here's a link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625140/horizontalalign-center-not-working-in-gridview

Comment: support for your answer from me :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes accepted answer will not do the job (css is forced by style sheet and/or skin file).
In this case you can set custom css class (if you want to align specific column):

```
.alignRight {
    text-align: right !important;
}
```

Next you need to attach to your GridView `RowDataBound` Event and set css on specific Column:

```
    protected void SumGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            string forcedCss = "alignRight";

            //TODO: change your col index:
            e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = forcedCss;
        }
    }
```